# Создание hashmap Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Имеется текст, находящийся в файле. Требуется создать HashMap, где ключ равен первой букве слов в тексте, а значение - список всех слов, начинающихся с этой буквы. Если буква содержит менее 10 слов, то требуется объединить их (пример: А-Б, В, Г, ..., Е-Л, М-Я) (то есть объединения в соответствии с алфавитным порядком). Вернуть HashMap, где ключ - это буква или диапазон, а значения - список слов ( первая буква которых располагается в заданном диапазоне  / или является заданной буквой). Требуется выполнить задание с использованием stream.

Начало реализовала так:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> splitArrayOfUsersByName(String filePath) {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(
            line.split("\\W+")
        ))
        .filter(x -> x.length() > 0)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            word -> word.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1), HashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));

  }
```

Таким образом удалось получить список слов, соответствующий буквам. Однако как далее объединить их - пока что идей нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи стримы не слишком подходят, так как здесь необходимо хранить некоторое состояние при вычислении нового ключа в зависимости от выполнения условия.

При помощи Stream API можно построить промежуточную мапу "буква - список слов", а результат придется строить по некоторому заранее определённому алфавиту.

Также хотел заметить, что регулярное выражение разбиения строки на слова `"\\W+"` предназначено для обработки слов, состоящим из букв английского алфавита, цифр и знака подчёркивания [`\w=[A-Za-z_0-9]; \W = [^\w]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  Слова на кириллице будут полностью отброшены, так как буквы будут входить в диапазон разделителей.

Вариант решения:

```java
public static Map<String, List<String>> map(Stream<String> data, String alphabet, int min) {
    Map<Character, List<String>> raw = data
        // разбить по пробелам и символам пунктуации
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("[\\p{Z}\\p{P}]+")))
        // убрать пустые строки
        .filter(w -> !w.isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            w -> Character.toUpperCase(w.charAt(0))
        ));
        
    Map<String, List<String>> res = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    List<String> merged = new ArrayList<>();
    String key = "";
    for (int i = 0, n = alphabet.length(); i < n; i++) {
        Character c = alphabet.charAt(i);
        List<String> words = raw.get(c);
        if (null != words)
            key += c;          // включать только буквы имеющихся слов
        merged.addAll(words);
        if (words.size() >= min) {
            // "улучшить" ключ
            res.put(key.replaceAll("(\\p{L})(\\p{L}*)(\\p{L})", "$1-$3"), new ArrayList<>(merged));
            merged.clear();
            key = "";
        }
    }
    if (!key.isEmpty())
        res.put(key.replaceAll("(\\p{L})(\\p{L}*)(\\p{L})", "$1-$3"), new ArrayList<>(merged));
        
    return res;
}
```

Тест

```java
map(
    Stream.of(
        "Муха села на варенье, вот и все стихотворенье",
        "Сова, открывай, медведь пришёл!",
        "Прашу падергат и ждат атвета. Сава",
        " Что значит я? \"Я\" бывают разные."
    ), 
    "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ", 2
).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Результат:

```
А-В: [атвета, бывают, варенье, вот, все]
Ж-И: [ждат, значит, и, и]
М: [Муха, медведь]
Н-П: [на, открывай, пришёл, Прашу, падергат]
Р-С: [разные, села, стихотворенье, Сова, Сава]
Ч-Я: [Что, я, Я]
```

Если закомментировать проверку `if (null != words)`, вид ключей изменится соответствующим образом:

```
А-В: [атвета, бывают, варенье, вот, все]
Г-И: [ждат, значит, и, и]
Й-М: [Муха, медведь]
Н-П: [на, открывай, пришёл, Прашу, падергат]
Р-С: [разные, села, стихотворенье, Сова, Сава]
Т-Я: [Что, я, Я]
```